# Reload Visualforce Page After Update

Tags: visualforce, controller, process-builder

I have a Visualforce page on a custom object that has a commandButton to update a field on the custom object.  When that field is updated, a Process fires that then creates a case based on the information in the custom object record.  All works fine.  However, I would like to refresh the page once the Process fires.  Is this possible?

**CommandButton:**

```
<apex:commandButton rendered="{!(CC.Create_Case__c == false)}" value="Create Case" action="{!CreateCase}" style="background:#d699ff; padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px"/>
```

**Controller:**

```
public with sharing class VF_Controller_CreateCampaignCase{

public Campaign_Create_Request__c CCR;

    public VF_Controller_CreateCampaignCase(ApexPages.StandardController myController){
        this.CCR = (Campaign_Create_Request__c)myController.getRecord();
    }

    public Void CreateCase() {
            CCR.Create_Case__c = true;
            update CCR;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks everyone.  I got my problem resolved by changing the Void method in my controller to a PageReference method and then adding a redirect back to my current page.  Thanks for all your help!  Updated working code for my controller is below:

```
public with sharing class VF_Controller_CreateCampaignCase{

    public Campaign_Create_Request__c CCR;

    public VF_Controller_CreateCampaignCase(ApexPages.StandardController myController){
        this.CCR = (Campaign_Create_Request__c)myController.getRecord();
    }

    public PageReference CreateCase() {
        CCR.Create_Case__c = true;
        update CCR;

        PageReference tempPage = ApexPages.currentPage();            
        tempPage.setRedirect(true);
        return tempPage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad you sorted it!

Answer (score 2):

If your commandbutton fires an action in your controller, you should just need to make that method return a PageReference, and then return `null`

Such as:

```
public pageReference updateFields() {
    // do some magic
    return null;
}
```

(and then the action on your commandbutton is something like:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!updateFields}" value="Update!" />
```

)

Edit: That is, unless you already have all this in place and you *only* want to reload the page once your controller "knows" that the process has fired. Which might be more complicated.

Comment: for last one you should use action poller from page to ensure that some data has been updated -- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionPoller.htm

Comment: That would be a very neat way to do that!

Comment: @Simon - Yes, I already have the controller to update the field on my custom object.  I updated my original post with it.  I want to then refresh my VF page after the Process has completed.

Comment: @kurunve - Thanks.  I'll take a look at that, but does it continually refresh or can it just be a 1-tim refresh?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `<apex:actionFunction>` below is the code .

```
<apex:pageblocksection id="test">
<apex:actionfunction id="refresh" rerender="test"/>
<apex:commandButton reRender="test" />
</apex:pageblocksection>
```

Comment: Thanks.  However, I want to refresh to occur automatically.  I don't want the user to have to click a button to refresh.

Comment: Add your current commandButton  code to your question.

Comment: Add reRender to your commnd button. reRender="YourBlockId". I will edit my answer accordingly. This should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks.  I added reRender to the CommandButton in my post above, but it still doesn't refresh the page after the Process completes.