# Parent record page not updating with field changes [visualforce button]

Tags: apex, visualforce, tasks

I have a custom button on the Task page layout that when clicked opens a new Visualforce window with an expanded 'Comments' field. I can make changes to the comments field and save them, but when I do, and I am brought back to the Task record, the changes are not reflected. I have to manually update the page each time. How can I automatically refresh the page so I can see any changes that were made?

Visualforce page

```
<apex:page standardController="Task" extensions="TaskCommentsController" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:inputTextarea value="{!comments}" rows="20" cols="50"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!saveComments}" value="Save"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex controller

```
public class TaskCommentsController {
    private Task taskRecord;
    public String comments { get; set; }

    public TaskCommentsController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.taskRecord = (Task)stdController.getRecord();
        comments = taskRecord.Comments;
    }

    public PageReference saveComments() {
        taskRecord.Comments = comments;
        update taskRecord;
        return new PageReference('/' + taskRecord.Id);
    }

    public PageReference cancel() {
        return new PageReference('/' + taskRecord.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you try, remove the last return line in your saveComments() method and replace it with these? 
        PageReference tempPage = ApexPages.currentPage();            
        tempPage.setRedirect(true);
        return tempPage;
Source: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106252/reload-visualforce-page-after-update

Comment: This is not working. It does not take me back to the Task record , but instead leaves me on the Visualforce page